# Inserting html string into a jquery object?

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure:

```
var $html = $("<div id='a'><div id='b'><div id='c'></div></div></div>");
```

I want to insert the following into the $html structure under div `#c`:

```
var html = "<div id='d'><div id='e'><div id='f'></div></div></div>";
```

I tried the following:

```
var $newHtml = $($html).find("#c").append(html);
```

I thought now the variable `$newHtml` would point to div `#a` and all its descending elements including the newly appended ones.

However, `$newHtml` only contains the `#c` div and decendants.

How do I get the `#a` object and its descendents?

**Update:**

To clarify:

I have the jquery object `$html` and a string `html`.

I want to insert the html string into one the innermost element of the `$html` structure.

`both append & html works for it. The problem is, $newHtml only holds the elements of #c. $html contains all, including inserted elements.`

Comment: You should have wrapped your string in single quotes or escaped out the quotes as well `var $html = $('<div id="a"><div id="b"><div id="c"></div></div></div>');`

Comment: @fudgey: I didnt done copy paste of my code. I just typed manually. I ll edit it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do

```
$('#c').append(html);
```

There's no reason to set the result to a variable. Almost all jQuery methods return a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery), this allows you to chain methods together.

Comment: My problem is, the `div#a` and its descendent's are a string.

Comment: How is it a string? If it's on the page it's part of the DOM, which means you can access them based on their IDs. If it's not part of the page than jQuery can't help you: jQuery is for DOM manipulation, not string manipulation.

Comment: Did you noticed my update!!?? I think there should be a way to do it. I ll try to find it and post it here.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, both append & html works for it. The problem is, `$newHtml` only holds the elements of `#c`. `$html` contains all, including inserted elements. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think `$html` is already a jQuery object. so you don't need to use `$($html).find`, you can just do `$html.find`.

Also, I think you'll want to use the `html` method instead of `append`, though I could be wrong.

**EDIT**: [Yeah, I was wrong.](http://api.jquery.com/append/) Append should work fine.

Comment: @BoltClock Even though it tries to answer the question?

Comment: I have tried it. Both returns same jq obj. Because, i think, `.find()` will return only the found object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $newHtml = $('#c', $html).html(html);
```

Comment: It returns only `#c` and its elements.